# AWS beanstalk not building docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Part of my docker-compose.yaml file is:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginxProxy:
    image: nginxproxy
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles/nginxproxy/
```

When trying to run an elastic beanstalk environment with this, I get an error of:

> ECS task stopped due to: Essential container in task exited.
>   (nginxProxy: CannotPullContainerError: API error (404): repository
>   nginxproxy not found: does not exist or no pull access httpdbin: )

Does Elastic Beanstalk support building docker images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, to confirm, EB doesn't build for you. We have Docker Hub watching GitHub and building a container whenever code is pushed. Jenkins watches that and deploys to elastic beanstalk whenever a new container is built. I'm pretty sure there are AWS products that do all of this, if that's your thing. GitLab will also build containers for you, I think.

If you aren't deploying often enough / don't want to automate, `eb deploy` works great if you have the beanstalk CLI installed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no according to: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html#create_deploy_docker_ecs_images:

> Building custom images during deployment with a Dockerfile is not
>   supported by the multicontainer Docker platform on Elastic Beanstalk.
>   Build your images and deploy them to an online repository before
>   creating an Elastic Beanstalk environment.